# Menu not expanding on page if i come from a page with the menu on it as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

```js
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.links').click(function() {
        $("#myTopnav").removeClass("responsive");
      });
    });
```

```css
   ul.topnav {
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: #DDD;
        }
    
        ul.topnav li {float: left;}
    
        ul.topnav li a {
          display: inline-block;
          color: #B500FF;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 10px 10px;
          text-decoration: none;
          transition: 0.3s;
          font-size: 17px;
        }
    
        ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #555;color: #000;}
    
        ul.topnav li a:visited {color: #B500FF;}
    
        ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}
    
          ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
          ul.topnav li.icon {
            float: right;
            display: inline-block;
          }
          ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
          ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
          }
          ul.topnav.responsive li {
            float: none;
            display: inline;
          }
          ul.topnav.responsive li a {
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
          }
        @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="inner">
        <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
          <li class="links"><a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li class="links"><a href="bio.php">Bio</a></li>
          <li class="links"><a href="portfolio.php">Protfolio</a></li>
          <li class="links"><a href="film.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;- Film</a></li>
          <li class="links"><a href="clocks.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;- Clocks</a></li>
          <li class="links"><a href="machinery.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;- Machinery</a></li>
          <li class="links"><a href="truck.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;- Set Truck</a></li>
          <li class="links"><a href="for_sale.php">For Sale</a></li>
          <li class="links"><a href="for_sale.php?s=clocks">&nbsp;&nbsp;- Clocks</a></li>
          <li class="links"><a href="for_sale.php?s=memorabilia.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;- Movie Memorabilia</a></li>
          <li class="links"><a href="for_sale.php?s=stuff.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;- Stuff</a></li>
          <li class="links"><a href="stuff.php">Cool Stuff</a></li>
          <li class="links"><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li class="icon">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

I got this code from stack, it works just fine until I use a link to a page, with the same menu on it, it then will not expand the menu on this new page.
If I reload the page the menu then works just fine.

Comment: This is not valid `$(\'.links\')`

Comment: sorry its because its coming from a php page and that is in an echo so that will work

Comment: corrected to how it is displayed on the page.

Comment: the code looks good. You mean, after you click the link, the new page is loaded and then you click on the menu and the menu does not expand?

Comment: Yes, ex. on the film page, I click bio, then the menu on the bio page will not expand.

Comment: Dou you have the `$(document).ready...` function running there and also the css referenced?

Comment: css is referenced and works
$(document).ready.... isn't used anywhere, and does not seem to be on the page i got the code from.

Comment: The ready handler must run on every page load in order to make the navigation work. Put an `alert("running")` inside of the ready handler, then you can see if this code is executed, when you get on the BIO page. Good luck!

Comment: the alert goes off each time the page loads, including the using the links.
[film](http://whosjimmy.com/mobile/film.php) and 
[bio](http://whosjimmy.com/mobile/bio.php) pages
its under construction(only 2 menu links that work) and design to be viewed on a mobile